# React datepicker return 'null' and invalid data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker

I'm trying to write a simple todo App and The problem is that i got 'invalid data' in the datepicker input and datepicker return 'null' in object. I guess, the main issue in the datepicker, but don't know what exactly should i look for.

```
    const [addTodo] = useMutation(ADD_TODO)
    const onSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        addTodo({
            variables:{
                title:todo.title,
                detail:todo.detail,
                date:todo.date,
            }, refetchQueries: [
                { query: GET_TODOS }
            ]
        })
    }
```

```
            <DatePicker
                onSubmit={onSubmit}
                id="date"
                value={moment(todo.date)}
                onChange={e => setTodo ({...todo, date: e.target.value})}
                dateFormat="dd MM yyyy"
                className={'bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 sm:text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full pl-10 p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500'}
                showDisabledMonthNavigation
            />
```

Comment: You can try: `onChange={(date) => setTodo({...todo, date})}`. But without seeing your todo structure it's only possible to speculate.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help. What exactly structure of project are needed? I'm new to the SO, so please be patient.

Comment: It's recommended to follow [these guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) when creating a question. If you post the complete code for the component that is using `<DatePicker>` that might help.